# Hibernate and equals()

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I might've read somewhere that:

1. Hibernate does not write to the database if an entity to be saved has no changes to it persistent state in the database.
2. Hibernate uses an entity's equals() to determine if it contains any changes to it persistent state.

Can anyone confirm or deny them?

Also, does any of these apply to the JPA specification?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Is correct if the entity has been loaded in the same hibernate session. (If the entity has been loaded in a previous session, and been reassociated with the current one, hibernate no longer has the old state for comparison and issues an update just in case).
2. Hibernate records the property values an object had when it was loaded in the hibernate session, and compares the current property values to the old property values, emitting an update if any are dirty. When comparing old and new property values, equals may be used. Equals is *not* used for comparing the old with the new entity. (There is no "old entity"). Relevant parts of the hibernate source:

   - [org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.dirtyCheck](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/org/hibernate/event/def/DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.html#dirtyCheck%28FlushEntityEvent%29)
   - [org.hibernate.type.TypeFactory.findDirty](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/org/hibernate/type/TypeFactory.html#findDirty%28StandardProperty,%20Object,%20Object,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20SessionImplementor%29)

Comment: Markdown hates me - feel free to edit if you know how to give it a URL containing spaces.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that Hibernate has its own mechanism for flagging dirty fields that need persisting to the database, and it does not involve equals.

Hibernate has some discussions about identity as the proper way to implement equals for persistent objects.  Checking [equality](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/EqualsandHashCode) of primary keys is sufficient in that case.

Answer (score 1):

First is correct, but I'm not sure about the second.

Usually, the `equals()` method should be overriden to implement custom comparison logic, ie. if you have primary key then two objects are equal if they match the key, otherwise you have to match their properties/attributes. So that's why I don't **think** it's used to detect changes, even because Hibernate would have to retrieve the current instance from DB which costs a query when you can do the `UPDATE` right away (but `SELECT` is far more faster than `UPDATE`)

Answer (score 0):

1). Hibernate roughly makes following checks 
 - New Entity: if id of an object exists. it is a new object it will be saved. 
 - Existing Entity: if id is null this object is not new and exists in the database. hibernate will check if any property of the object has beend changed (dirty flag) if yes it will be updated in the database.

2). You need to implement equals method if you intent to put instances to map and intent to reattacht of detached instances. For example you have a detached object which already exists in the database if you want to attach this object in order to update it, you have to implement equals method.

see http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch04.html#persistent-classes-equalshashcode